# How can i solve Larger file import error in wamp - Out of memory

Tags: magento-1.9, memory, wamp, gzip

I need to import exported db, when i try to import i get error like,

[image]

As per error line, what can i do,

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a Magento question and is more related to phpMyAdmin. It should be asked on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism : Magento developers at-least once faced this problem, that's what am asking, and also found solution here. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these different settings in C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.8\bin\php.ini

Find:

```
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 8M
```

Change to:

```
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M
```

Then restart wamp to take effect

Comment: @ ashar :its working.....